# Create batch file for bulk renaming pdf files in a folder in windows 7

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-rename

We are a daily news paper agency, our news paper comes with 40 pages. For submitting the news paper(PDF files) to press reader we need to rename all the 40 page into a specific format i.e  **PGTVD_DDMMYYYY_001*.pdf**

The DDMMYY will replaced by specific dates and page numbers will be automatically increased from 1 to 40.

I want to create a batch file, by running which i can be able to renaming all the files at a time.

Please help me how to do that.

Thanks in advance

Chandra Sekhar

Comment: What is the base for the whole thing? If there is just a bunch of files in a folder how would you determine which to rename and in which order? Further you should be able to do that with a bit of research... Assuming the files are there named 001.pdf , 002.pdf and so on. **For** each file in the directory, generate a string based on todays **date**, **rename** the files to PGTVD_<your string here>_<oldname>.pdf   .

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Yes the file is in a folder with names like page1, page2, page3....upto page 40. I want to rename all the 40 pages like PGTVD_DDMMYYYY_001 to PGTVD_DDMMYYYY_040. 

This is my requirement. Kindly help thanks

Comment: Do you enter the date every time or take the current one?

Answer (score 0):

This batch uses the current date if not supplied a date as first command line arg.

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set PreFix=PGTVD

:: Get current date
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=.+-" %%A in (
  'wmic os get LocalDateTime^|findstr ^^[0-9]'
    ) do Set _DT=%%A
Set "MyDate=%_DT:~6,2%%_DT:~4,2%%_DT:~0,4%"
If "%~1" Neq "" Set "MyDate=%~1"

For /f "delims=" %%A in (
  'Dir /B/A-D/ON Page*.pdf'
) Do Call :RenSub "%%~fA"
Timeout /T -1
Goto :Eof
:RenSub
Set Name=%~n1
Set /A No=1000+%Name:~4%
Echo Ren %1 "%PreFix%_%MyDate%_%No:~-3%%~x1"
```

The rename commands are only echoed, if the output looks right remove the echo in the last line.